# Restrict Multiple Items in Json

Tags: jsonschema

I am creating a JSON schema in which a field is a array field and can have two custom types. Now i want that this field can have one custom type with max item as 1 and another as 0 to n.

```
"field-1": {
    "type": "array",
    "system-generated": true,
    "anyOf": [{
            "items": {
                "$ref": "customItem1"
            }
        }, {
            "items": {
                "$ref": "customItem2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Considering the above same, i want that field-1 have customItem1 max one instance and customItem2 have zero to n instances.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to enforce that an array contains a specific number of something. The closest you can do is to enforce that something exists (1 to n) in an array.

If "customItem1" is always the first item, it can be done.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "items": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/customItem1" }
      ],
      "additionalItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/customItem2" },
    },
    {
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/customItem2" }
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "customItem1": { "type": "string" },
    "customItem2": { "type": "boolean" }
  }
}
```